# Service cannot be started. The service process could not connect to the service controller when start service

Tags: c#, web-services, service-installer, serviceinstall

I create a service like this :

```
private SocketDataRepository socketRepository = new SocketDataRepository();
        SerivceIPconfigRepository serivceIPconfigRepository=new SerivceIPconfigRepository();
        public AsyncCallback pfnWorkerCallBack;
        private Socket m_mainSocket;
        private Socket[] m_workerSocket = new Socket[25];
        private int m_clientCount = 0;
        private string ipaddress;
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceIpConfig serviceIpConfig = serivceIPconfigRepository.GetAll().First();
            DrawMapPersian();
            ipaddress = serviceIpConfig.IncomingIP;
            // Check the port value

            string portStr = serviceIpConfig.IncomingPort;
            int port = System.Convert.ToInt32(portStr);
            // Create the listening socket...
            m_mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                      SocketType.Stream,
                                      ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            // Bind to local IP Address...
            m_mainSocket.Bind(ipLocal);
            // Start listening...
            m_mainSocket.Listen(4);
            // Create the call back for any client connections...
            m_mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
        }
    protected override void OnContinue()
    {
        base.OnContinue();
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }
```

As you can see my service listens to a port for incoming data .I also add an installer for my service as you can see here :

```
 [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class MyWindowsServiceInstaller : Installer
    {
        public MyWindowsServiceInstaller()
        {
            var processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            var serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

            //set the privileges
            processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

            serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "My Service";
            serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Manual;

            //must be the same as what was set in Program's constructor
            serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "My Service";

            this.Installers.Add(processInstaller);
            this.Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
        }
    }
```

I install my service using `installutil.exe` .everything works fine and my service installed and i can see it in list of services .but when i try to start that i got this error :

[image]

I check the log event and my error is this:

```
 Provider 

   [ Name]  My Service 

  - EventID 0 

   [ Qualifiers]  0 

   Level 2 

   Task 0 

   Keywords 0x80000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2014-08-17T15:38:21.000000000Z 

   EventRecordID 7526 

   Channel Application 

   Computer ehsan-PC 

   Security 


- EventData 

   Service cannot be started. The service process could not connect to the service controller
```

Where is my problem ?

Comment: Remove all code in `OnStart()`, build/deploy/check if it starts correctly.

Comment: Yes it works and starts so what is the problem

Comment: Use `try..catch` block inside `OnStart()` and log the exception to file. Also if possible test the `OnStart()` code separately in a console application to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @cackharot thank you again i put a try catch and write my error that is got by catch into a txt file .